# Provisional headers are shown only in Mobile Device

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just deployed my angular 2 cli web app project to AWS S3,
everything works well on desktop, but for my Android Device, when I try to call a POST http request (not sure about other calls), the request is pending with headers caution `Provisional headers are shown`.

It only happens in Mobile devices. why is this happening ? and how do I resolve it ?

Comment: What is your request look like, is it authenticated?

Comment: Just POST method, to https://example.com/login with some headers request and few custom headers. Yes it is authenticated

Comment: My request looks like this, `Request URL: http://example.com/login`, `Request Method: POST`,  Request Headers => `Accept: application/json`, `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, `Authorization: Something 12345abcde12345`, `X-Custom-Something: something`. My apology for the messy format.

Comment: @AngJobs, nevermind, it was the server configuration that prevents connection without VPN. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Correction, it wasn't because of mobile device's ajax call, it's merely caused by my device not connected via VPN, causing the API request not being made.